# how to get current product category name in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

In WooCommerce single produce page I'm using some custom fields but one tab (see attachment picture right side tab 'Residential') I'd like to get the product category, which only one will be ticked. But I'm very unsure what code is needed to get that?

Image: https://ibb.co/XJ7FvmT

[image]

Any help to extract one product category name would be much appreciated.

The product (a property) will only have one category. Ie. Land, Residential, Commercial, Industry etc.

Thanks

Here is some code from image that's from the add_action in functions.php

```
    <!-- Advanced Custom Feilds-->            
<span class="property-contract-badge"><?php echo get_field('listing_status'); ?></span>
<span class="property-type-badge"><?php echo get_field('property_category'); ?></span>

<!-- Get Woocommerce product category -->        
<span class="property-type-badge"><?php echo $product->get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat'); ?></span>
```

Comment: Do you want to show all categories?

Comment: No, just one product category. 99.99% of the time, the product (a property) will only have one category. Ie. Land, Residential, Commercial, Industry etc. Thanks

Comment: Where did you add this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
<span class="property-type-badge">
    <?php   
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat' );
        $term  = reset($terms);
        echo $term->name;
    ?>
</span>
```